# Chef cookbooks with BOSH

Tags: chef-infra, cf-bosh

I am trying to use Chef cookbooks with BOSH deployment. 
Is it possible to install BOSH packages using Chef cookbooks? If yes, is there any blog which lists the specific steps for it?

Comment: interesting - I was thinking about the very same question. But as @coderanger stated in the comment below, it seems to me as if it would make little sense, since BOSH uses it's very own "format" for packages deployed on a machine and you wouldn't gain much benefit from using Chef here. Also the concept of idempotency (one of the core principles of Chef) seems to be of little use for me once you have "immutable infrastructure" like in a BOSH deployment (never update, always throw away and start from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it possible, there is a semi-official cookbook from the CF folks: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/chef-bosh_agent

Comment: This link shows to install BOSH agent using  a chef cookbook. But I wanted to know if BOSH can use an existing chef cookbook to install a software. For example, If I want to install MySQL via a chef cookbook, Is it possible to make this installation done via BOSH command line instead of Chef?

Comment: While you might be able to hack that in somehow, that isn't how BOSH works. BOSH jobs really only install their own special format for packages.